# Java project hierarchy in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a difference between a package and a folder in eclipse?
for example, if I have this hierarchy requirement:

```
java –classpath  C:\ChatCompany\BackendChatServer\ 
  -Djava.security.policy=c:\HW2\permissions.policy 
   hw2.chat.backend.main.ChatBackendServer
```

when the package's name is:

```
hw2.chat.backend.main
```

, and "`ChatCompany\BackendChatServer\`" is the folder name.

Then how can I make this separation between a package and a folder in eclipse, so that I can write:

```
package hw2.chat.backend.main;
```

, and not "`package ChatCompany.BackendChatServer.hw2.chat.backend.main`"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- define your root project outside of the workspace. The root of the project (where the `.eclipse` and `.classpath` are actually created) will be at `C:\ChatCompany` for instance.
- make `BackendChatServer` the source folder, under which all sub-directories like `hw2` will be created as part of the package path of a Java class.
- make the output of the compilation in the same directory than the sources.

That way:

- you can write "`package hw2.chat.backend.main`"
- you can have a classpath set to "`C:\ChatCompany\BackendChatServer\`"

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I create a project in eclipse I can add a source folder apart from the default "src", so I added this folder name: `ChatCompany\BackendChatServer`, and then this line gets added to the .classpath file at the root of the project:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="ChatCompany/BackendChatServer"/>.
```

I suppose you can also add the folders manually outside eclipse, but then you have to change the .classpath yourself.